# How to get the integers and text to wordwrap with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

when a user scans in bar codes and enters the numbers into the text field the numbers keep moving to the right of the screen. I need them to wrap is there a better way to write this table to do that? when user scans numbers in and hit space bar they wrap no issue.

```html
<?php
require_once("../db_connect.php");

$stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received'");
echo"Received Requests";
echo "<br><br>";
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo("<table  bgcolor=F2F2F2 width=1080 border='2'>");

echo("<br><tr><th>Id</th><th>Update</th><th>LanID</th><th>Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Manager</th><th>request</th><th>Description</th><th>request_comments</th><th>Status</th><th>Comments</th><th>Completed User</th><th>Completed Date</th></tr>");

echo("<tr>");
echo  "<td>". $row['id'] . "</td>"
."<td><a href='../update.php?id="  . $row['id'] .  "'>Update</a></td>"
."<td>" .  $row['lanId'] . "</td> "
. "<td>".  $row['name'] . "</td>"
. "<td>". $row['department'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['manager'] . "</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_description'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['request_comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['status'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['comments'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compUser'] ."</td>"
. "<td>" . $row['compDt'] ."</td>";
echo '</tr>';
echo("</table>");
}


?>

<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
<title></title>
</head>
<body background="../images/background.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

I also rewrote the code this way.I also split the tables so they could all fit.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>

<head>

<title>Received Requests</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//conects to the database
require_once("../db_connect.php");

//prepared statement with PDO to query the database
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE status='Received'");
$stmt->execute();

echo"Received Requests";
?>

<?php //start of the while loop ?>
<?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
```

```
<br>
<tr> 
    <th style="width:25px">ID</th>
    <th style="width:65px">Date Requested</th>
    <th style="width:40px">LanId</th>
    <th style="width:140px ">Name</th>
    <th style="width:125px">Dept.</th>
    <th style="width:140px">Manager</th>
    <th style="width:100px">Request</th>

</tr>
<tr style="width:25px">
<?php $id = $row['id'];?>
<?php echo  "<td> <a href='../update.php?id=$id'>$id</a></td>"?>
    <td style="width:65px"><?php echo $row['date_requested']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:40px"><?php echo $row['lanId']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:140px"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:125px"><?php echo $row['department']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:140px"><?php echo $row['manager']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px"><?php echo $row['request']; ?></td>

</tr>

</table>
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 1080px;">

<tr> 
    <th style="width:130px">Request Desc.</th>
    <th style="width:140px">Request comments</th>
    <th style="width:80px">Status</th>
    <th style="width:160px">Comments</th>
    <th style="width:40px">Comp. User</th>
    <th style="width:65px">Comp. Date</th>  
</tr>
<tr style="width:25px">

    <td style="width:130px; word-break: break-all;"><?php echo $row['request_description']; ?></td>
    <td><textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 235px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['request_comments']; ?></textarea></td>
    <td style="width:80px"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
    <td><textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 270px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['comments']; ?></textarea></td>
    <td style="width:40px"><?php echo $row['compUser']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:65px"><?php echo $row['compDt']; ?></td>
</tr>


</table>
  <?php } //end of the while loop?>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [word wrap does not let the numbers wrap also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836287/word-wrap-does-not-let-the-numbers-wrap-also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to help other people who have same issue. Because most of the wrap questions on this site do not cover the fact the numbers do not wrap. No matter if you try fixed width of the table or wrapword on the td does not work either. You have to put a textarea box in the td to get the number to wrap.

Here is what I used for all the rows needing numbers wrapped.

```
<td><textarea name="request_comments"  style="width: 235px; height: 81px" style="text-transform:uppercase ;"><?php echo $row['request_comments']; ?></textarea></td>
```

Comment: also this example still does not work for numbers only text wrap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836287/word-wrap-does-not-let-the-numbers-wrap-also