# word wrap does not let the numbers wrap also

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this form which is working The only thing is  when user enters  a lot of digits into the textbox numbers

Example:

```
12345678
3567892
1235674
36778883
566666678
35674748999
// with no spaces
```

It does not want to wrap. I looked all over the net it only shows how to wrap text.

```
<html>
<?php

require_once("connect.php");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbers");
$stmt->execute();

?>
<?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>

<table border='1'table-layout: fixed >
<br>
<tr> 
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>numbers</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo $row['numbers']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should it look like in the end?

Comment: just a results page with a table.Thing is the numbers make the table go all the way to the right instead of wrapping

Comment: Can you cast them as a string if it's just for output? Also, your table has more headers than TDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to designate a width of the table thru css.

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 150px;">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th style="word-wrap: break-word;">numbers</th>

    </tr>
    <?php while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo $row['numbers']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```